# cartesian product of two output in shell

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a shell script to extract the filename and columns from a given file:
and a sample file which needs to be read from directory is:

```
2222_AAA Accounting Statistic-42005_04May2020_0900-04May2020_1000.csv


#!/bin/bash

# Go to where the files are located
filedir=/home/vikrant_singh_rana/AAA_USP/sample-Files/*

for filename in $filedir
do
 #echo "Processing $filepath"
 # do something on $f
 printf '%s,%s\n' "$(basename "$filename" ".csv" | grep -oP '(?<=_).*(?=\-\d\d\d)' )" "$(head -n1 "$filename")"

done > test.txt;
```

Above shell script will produce the following output as:
filename and header columns from input file

```
cat test.txt
AAA Accounting Statistic,TIMESTAMP,C420050004,C420050005,C420050006,C420050007
```

I was expecting a cartisian product of file name and the columns which are there in the file:

```
AAA Accounting Statistic,TIMESTAMP
AAA Accounting Statistic,C420050004
AAA Accounting Statistic,C420050005
AAA Accounting Statistic,C420050006
AAA Accounting Statistic,C420050007
```

Comment: You need a second loop with the `for` loop to run across the result of `head -n1 "$filename"`.

Comment: @nohillside.. Could you please answer it with the exact code.. would be great help

Comment: What is the original filename that is picked up from `/home/vikrant_singh_rana/AAA_USP/sample-Files/*`? Is it something that contains the string `AAA Accounting Statistic`?  Also, what constitutes  the cartesian product that you are talking about here?

Comment: its like 2222_AAA Accounting Statistic-42005_04May2020_0900-04May2020_1000.csv. why it has been downvoted?

Comment: If you add that information to the question, the question would be complete. I downvoted because it lacked this relevant info.

Comment: @ Kusalananda.. got it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a second loop to handle the first line of `$filename`

```
for filename in /home/vikrant_singh_rana/AAA_USP/sample-Files/*; do
    # ...
    b=$(basename "$filename" ".csv" | grep -oP '(?<=_).*(?=\-\d\d\d)' )
    for c in $(head -n1 "$filename" | sed 's/,/ /g'); do
        printf '%s,%s\n' "$b" "$c"
    done
done > test.txt
```

<sub>PS: This assumes that there are no space characters or newlines in the first line of `$filename`.</sub>

Comment: Either turn `filedir` into an array of filenames and then loop over `"${filedir[@]}"`, or loop over the actual globbing pattern. Using `$filedir` unquoted disqualifies the script from working on files with spaces and/or filename globbing characters in their names (the question hints that the filename contains the string `AAA Accounting Statistic`).  Also, that unquoted command substitution would do _interesting_ things if the `$filename` file happened to contain filename globbing characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

for pathname in /home/vikrant_singh_rana/AAA_USP/sample-Files/*.csv
do
    name=${pathname##*/}   # remove directory path
    name=${name#*_}        # remove *_ prefix (up to first underscore)
    name=${name%%-*}       # remove -* suffix (from first dash)

    awk -F , -v name="$name" 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) print name, $i; exit }' "$pathname"
done
```

This iterates over all your CSV files, and removes the directory path and initial `NNNN_` string from the name, as well as everything after the first `-` character.  This string is kept in `$name`.

A short `awk` program is then run on the file, which prints out the fields from the first line of the file on separate lines, each prefixed by the extracted value in `$name`.

This assumes that the CSV file is a *simple* CSV file with no embedded commas or newlines in the fields of the first line.

---

If you don't have many thousands of files, you could also use GNU `awk` like so:

```sh
awk -F , '
    BEGIN { OFS=FS }
    BEGINFILE {
        name = FILENAME
        sub(".*/", "", name)       # remove directory path
        sub("^[^_]*_", "", name)   # remove *_ prefix (up to first underscore)
        sub("-.*", "", name)       # remove -* suffix (from first dash)
    }
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) print name, $i
        nextfile
    }' /home/vikrant_singh_rana/AAA_USP/sample-Files/*.csv
```

Comment: @Kusalananda.Thank you for detailed explanation.